# How to know when com0com port installation is complete?

Tags: installation, com0com

I am writing InstallAware script which installs com0com, creates several COM ports and also installs my application which uses those ports.

To create ports I run setupc.exe install with some options. Setupc does its job and quits very quickly. After that Windows starts its lengthy process telling user that a new device was found and do they want to install driver etc.

At the end of the installation process user sees standard screen saying that installation finished, do you want to run the app. I get to this point before windows finished installing drivers and can't proceed before it is done.

How can I know when all driver were installed and ports were created and I can use them?

I thought of writing a small app which would periodically try to open my ports. Installation script would wait till this app quits and then proceed to the final screen.

Is there any other way? Can I get any notification from Windows that driver installation is complete?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with InstallAware, but you should be able to pull the available serial ports and whether they match up on your application side.  Allow the user to start the application but have a check in the beginning that waits until all your serial ports are created and available then proceed.  You could also check if the process that creates your com0com ports is running before continuing to the final screen, but once again I'm not sure the capabilities of InstallAware.